# Meteor.loginWithGoogle show scopes permission again and again

Tags: authentication, scope, permissions, google-signin

I am facing an issue related to permission. Once the user allows the permission and log-out it's asked again for permissions if the user tries to log-in.

here is my code

```
const requestPermissions = {
    google: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
    ],
};

Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions,
    requestOfflineToken: { google: true },
    forceApprovalPrompt: { google: true },
    passwordSignupFields: process.env.debugMode ? 'EMAIL_ONLY' : null,
    requireEmailVerification: process.env.debugMode ? false : null,
    minimumPasswordLength: process.env.debugMode ? 8 : null
});

Meteor.loginWithGoogle({ 
 overrideRestrictDomain,
            requestPermissions: requestPermissions.google,
            loginUrlParameters: { include_granted_scopes: false }
        }, (err, done) => {
            console.log('google login', { err, done });
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have just added two properties that solve my problem.

```
forceApprovalPrompt = false;
approval_prompt = 'auto';
```

after adding **approval_prompt** google show prompt conflicts with prompt then I just removed the **prompt** and added **approval_prompt**